# Python loop creating

Tags: python

```
for line in f: 
    yo = f.readline(), 
    index = yo.find(':'),
    p = yo[0:index+1], 
    pic = yo[index+1:len(yo)], 
    print ('zz' + p),
f.close()
```

SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Why can't I assign my variable (yo) to f.readline() in loop but can do it when it's not in loop?

Comment: Welcome to SO! To make sure that you get good answer - please clearly state your question/problem and what have you tried to resolve it.

Comment: Given the , answer and your original lack of formatting the OP needs to confirm exactly what things are (especially given the multiple edits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: assuming "," at the end are just typos.

You should always (in 99% cases) use `with` statement when working with files:

```
with open("filename") as f:
    for yo in f:
        index = yo.find(':')
        p = yo[0:index+1]
        pic = yo[index+1:len(yo)]
        print ('zz' + p)
```

To answer your question, after `for line in f:` cycle is done `f.readline()` will not return what you probably expect from it.

P.S. Consider this 'pythonic' optimization:

```
with open("filename") as f:
    for yo in f:
        p, pic = yo.split(':', 1)
        print('zz{p}:'.format(p=p))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably remove the commas from all those lines, since it is making your variables equal to 1-tuples.

---

If you want to know why you are getting

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

it would be helpful to us if you showed a complete, minimal working example. How is `f` defined? What is the complete stack trace? On what line did the error occur?

If your script looks like

```
f = open('data')
for line in f: 
    yo = f.readline()
```

then you should be getting a `ValueError`, not a `SyntaxError`:

```
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    index = line.find(':')

    p = line[0:index+1]

    pic =line[index+1:len(yo)]

    print ('zz' + p)
```